# Проблема с Vega

Tags: javascript, html

Привет. Проблема с Vega -- библиотекой JS, позволяющей отрисовывать графики. У них на сайте с примерами беда. Есть, конечно, неплохие примеры формирования данных. Но, к сожалению, не могу найти Quick Start. Есть [usage](https://vega.github.io/vega/usage/), но он у меня не стартанул. Вот пример того, что у меня не запускается:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://vega.github.io/vega/vega.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://vega.github.io/vega-embed/vega-embed.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vis"></div>
<script>
  vega.embed('#vis', 'https://vega.github.io/vega/spec/bar.vg.json');
  // create a new view instance for a given Vega JSON spec
var view = new vega.View(vega.parse(spec))
  .renderer('none')
  .initialize();

// generate a static SVG image
view.toSVG()
  .then(function(svg) {
    // process svg string
  })
  .catch(function(err) { console.error(err); });

// generate a static PNG image
view.toCanvas()
  .then(function(canvas) {
    // process node-canvas instance
    // for example, generate a PNG stream to write
    var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
  })
  .catch(function(err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Нашёл [пример](http://vega.anneladyem.org/) на просторах интернета следующего содержания:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://trifacta.github.io/vega/vega.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <title>Vega tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="title">Let's Try Vega</h1>
  <div id="viz"></div>
  <div id="text"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parse(spec) {
        vg.parse.spec(spec, function(chart) { chart({el:"#viz", renderer: "svg"}).update(); });
    }
    parse("barchart.json");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Но он почему-то запускается непосредственно [на сайте](http://vega.anneladyem.org/). При создании html-ки, он стартовать не хочет:

[image: Html локальный]

Замечу, что на [сайте](http://vega.anneladyem.org/), помимо самой html больше ничего не приезжает:

[image: Список приехавших файлов]

Что я делаю не так? От чего локально не происходит отрисовка?

Comment: Chartist не подойдет? Там хорошие примеры :)  Локально может быть и оттого, что где-то не так указан путь к barchart.json

Comment: @labris Не, проблема была в другом. Можно глянуть на мой ответ.

Comment: @labris, спасибо за либу. Она мне больше понравилась.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что я не поглядел (в силу неопытности) на ошибки, которые выдал браузер.

Он говорил следующее:

[image: Ошибки]

Была ещё одна ошибка по поводу styles.css, но она ни на что не влияла. Как можно понять, запросы такого вида поддерживаются только для определённых протоколов. А у нас `file://`. Это нехорошо. Значит, заходим в консоль, поднимаем питоновский сервак (или любой другой): `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. Идём на `localhost:8000`, после чего переходим в директорию, в который лежит наш html:

[image: Путь к index.html]

Теперь посмотрим, что лежит в `barchart.json`. Для этого идём в [http://vega.anneladyem.org/barchart.json](http://vega.anneladyem.org/) и видим здесь `sarna.csv`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот файлик также необходимо скачать и добавить в папку, в которой лежит `index.html`: `http://vega.anneladyem.org/sarna.csv`.

Уаля, заработало:

[image: Заработало]

Comment: Но по качеству реализации либы, я бы советовал присмотреться к chartist. Она удобнее, особенно для новичков.